# Native Mobile browser based apps

Tags: iphone, android, mobile

Wondering if someone could point me in the right direction, as I am unsure of the correct terminology. I am looking to create a mobile website, which loads in a browser based application (iPhone, Android).

I have seen this done before. For example, the bank of america application is actually installed via the App Store, however, it is simple a browser window that loads the Bank of America mobile site (which is built to look and function like an app).

I find this to more cost-effective, as developing a mobile app is less intense, as opposed to developing applications for 2-3 different mobile platforms.

Can someone provide insight into the terminology or methods used to accomplish this? Looking for articles, examples, etc.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) or [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), two of the bigger names in this "native wrapper" technology.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use **IBM Worklight**.

**Worklight** is an Eclipse-based visual development and server platform for mobile apps. Using Worklight and popular open technologies, you can build, test, deploy, and manage your smartphone and tablet apps for iOS, Android, Blackberry, and Windows Phone devices, with maximum code reuse and per-device optimization.

Worklight supports open technologies such as HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, Apache Cordova, and popular JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery, Dojo Mobile, and Sencha Touch.
Worklight offers extensive runtime libraries and client APIs that expose and interface with native device functionality.
Worklight includes a browser simulator so you can test and optimize the user experience of your mobile content on varying mobile devices.

Worklight consists of an IDE (Worklight Studio), a Java-based server, device runtime components, a web-based console for managing deployments, and an application center.

for more info see
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html